# Google oAuth doesn't invalidate token string after log out from Google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I use Google oAuth to login my website.  This is perfectly works fine for sign in. But it doesn't work for logout.

I do below,

1. Get idTokenString from Google API
2. Keep it with my session
3. Verify this token for each request by GoogleIdTokenVerifier

When user does below action google doesn't invalidates the token instead it sends success response.

1. A user logged in Google
2. Access my website by allow access
3. The user Logged out from google
4. The user accesses my website,
5. My system sends the token to verify it.
6. Google gives me idToken, so my system allows the user to access my website

When the user closes the browser and come back then the token invalidated and my system doesn't allow. But without closing the browser it doesn't work

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Please go through accepted answer. This is expected behaviour, it provides authorization services not authentication. I have implemented my own session management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. If user is logging out of the google it will not logout from your application as well. 
However, there is a work around if you want to logout user from your application and want google to be also logged out. You just have to clear all the cookies from the browser programatically OR  you could dynamically build the logout url from one of their Google services logout button, and then invoke that using an img element or a script tag in your application.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en" />
```

OR

```
<img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en" />
```

OR

```
window.location = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en";
```

Comment: I don't have log out from my system, Im just relying on Google. Please consider this scenario.  User using public computer and accessed my web site then logged out from google without closing the browser. In this scenario any one can access my website

Comment: As Luke said, the behaviour is as expected. OAuth is about authorization, NOT authentication and session management for your application. You need to build your own sessions on top of the tokens that OAuth provides.